# Highchart polar chart with scatter in specific directions

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highcharts Polar chart, how can I plot each point in specific direction. For instance 5 in 35°, 7 in 90°, 10 in 187°, 2 in 0° etc.
Like this image
[image]

This is what I have

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            polar: true
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Polar Chart'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 360
        },

        xAxis: {
            tickInterval: 45,
            min: 0,
            max: 360,
            labels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + '°';
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                pointStart: 0,
                pointInterval: 45
            },
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0,
                groupPadding: 0
            }
        },

        series: [{
            type: 'scatter',
            name: 'Column',
            data: [8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,0,
                        16,15,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,
                        8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1,0],
            pointPlacement: 'on'
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: By providing the appropriate x value for each data point. Your data, as given, will simply plot each point in increasing x axis order. Provide the data as an array of [x,y] arrays instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. if you want, please post the answer with the example so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By providing the appropriate x value for each data point.

Your data, as given, will simply plot each point in increasing x axis order. Provide the data as an array of `[x,y]` arrays instead